# inserting multiple notationed preg_match_all element into mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, preg-match-all

I have variables gathered from another website with **preg_match_all** and echo the value. But the value is in $var1[0][n], n>0 form;I couldn't inserted the value into mysql.
Thanks for any help.

```
$path='@<div class="comp-cell-row-div vtable infoColumn" style="width:    25%;">(.*?)</div>@si';
$vr12=file_get_contents('https://www....');
preg_match_all($path,$vr12,$ad12);
echo $ad12[0][14];

$value = array( var_dump($ad12));

foreach($value as $val){mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `test` SET     `param1`='$val' WHERE `id`='118'");
}

 or mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `test` VALUES .....");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we need to manipulate data. Choose db as varchar to see saved tags with data. Pregmatc_all also gets tags, strings in varchar format.
To eleminate unwanted tags or signs; use trim and substr expressions on php.

In the example I trim before 17th character. This is a property of strpos

```
$data12=trim(substr($ad12[0][n], 17, strpos($ad12[0][n],'')),$extratags);
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `table` SET `val12` = '$data12' WHERE `col1` = 'data1'; ");
```